# How can I customize the output of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins builds our code, via a batch script build step. The output/error streams are captured and displayed in the build page. Can I do something to highlight the errors? For example, I would like to colour in red all the lines that contain the string `error SOME_CODE`, and in yellow all the warnings.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) can do this:

> The log-parser plugin allows to parse the flat console log generated
> by the Hudson build. It does this by :
>
> - highlighting lines of interest in the log (errors, warnings,
>   information)
> - dividing the log into sections
> - displaying a summary of number of errors , warnings and information
>   lines within the log and its sections.
> - linking the summary of errors and warnings into the context of the
>   full log, making it easy to find a line of interest in the log
> - showing a summary of errors and warnings on the build page

Comment: It looks like this plugin can do everything I need. However, I don't have any parsing rules in the option menu. How could I configure what an error/warnings looks like?

Comment: I found it in the global section. I'm doing a build right now and I will tell you how it went.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to customize it, and now everything's perfect :)